# Linux, how to parsing for pci express NVMe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm working on bash script getting the pci nvme address for hot reset.

I want to parsing for pci express nvme ADDRESS (i.e /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.2/0000:02:00.0/**0000:03:00.0**/nvme/nvme0

how can i do this?

I want to parse the address value before **nvme**.

Comment: Split it into an array on `/` characters, then get the 7th element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar thx, im trying to "> cut" command, but other motherboard has not working. so, i think required that Bash script to Auto detected PCI ADDR.
"> cut" command has limitation for specific motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut` with `/` as the delimiter.

```
addr='/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:01:00.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/nvme/nvme0'
nvme=$(cut -d/ -f8 <<<"$addr")
echo "$nvme"
```